# How to differentiate between devices in the windows HID API?

Tags: windows, hidapi

I need to detect when a gamepad is plugged in for my game (I'm not using a higher-level input API for reasons), how can I do this? I've already enumerated all HID devices and opened files on them (except keyboard, mouse ofc) and can get all the info on the device, but what info do I want? What value(s) will tell me right away that this is an xbox controller, for example, and where are these values?

My code for enumerating over the devices (very messy atm :p):

```
    DWORD required_size = 0, determined_size;
    SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA device_interface_data;
    device_interface_data.cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA);
    PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA device_interface_detail_data;
    HANDLE current_device;
    PHIDP_PREPARSED_DATA preparsed_data;
    WCHAR product_string[128];

    for (int i = 0; ; ++i) /* Enumerate HID devices */
    {
        rv = SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(device_enumeration, NULL, &interface_guid, i, &device_interface_data); /* Does the actual enumeration,
                                                                                                                each time we increase index i
                                                                                                                to get the next device */      
        error = GetLastError();
        if (error == ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS) /* If there are no more devices, break */
            break;
        else if (!rv && error != ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS) /* Otherwise, we have a legit error */
        {
            cr_print_error(GetLastError());
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(device_enumeration, &device_interface_data, NULL, 0, &required_size, NULL); /* Probing call only to get buffer size,
                                                                                                                    so error code (122) ignored */
        /* Allocate new device detail struct using buffer size we obtained */
        determined_size = required_size;
        device_interface_detail_data = cr_safe_malloc(required_size);
        device_interface_detail_data->cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA);

        /* Get detailed info about device */
        rv = SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(device_enumeration, &device_interface_data, device_interface_detail_data, determined_size, &required_size, NULL);

        if (!rv)
        {
            cr_print_error(GetLastError());
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        cr_printf("FOUNDD DEVICE: %s\n\n", device_interface_detail_data->DevicePath);
        
        current_device = cr_open_device(device_interface_detail_data->DevicePath);

        if (!current_device && GetLastError() == ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED)
            goto Done;

        cr_printf("OPENED DEVICE: %s\n\n", device_interface_detail_data->DevicePath);

        preparsed_data = HidD_GetPreparsedData(current_device, &preparsed_data);

        if (!preparsed_data)
        {
            cr_print_error(GetLastError());
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        HidD_GetProductString(current_device, product_string, sizeof(product_string));

        cr_printf("PRODUCT STRING: %S\n\n", product_string);

        HidD_FreePreparsedData(&preparsed_data);
        DeleteFile(device_interface_detail_data->DevicePath);
    Done:
        cr_safe_free(&device_interface_detail_data);
    }

    SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(device_enumeration);
```

As you can see I've found the product string, which tells me what the device actually is, but maybe comparing product strings is not the best way to do PnP?

Answer (score 1):

Check if the device ID contains "IG_".  If it does, then it's an XInput device.
[More info on that](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/xinput/xinput-and-directinput).

Alternatively you can check for XUSB [device interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows-hardware/drivers/install/using-a-device-interface):

```cpp
bool RawInputDeviceHid::QueryXInputDeviceInterface()
{
    DCHECK(IsValidHandle(m_InterfaceHandle.get()));

    // https://docs.microsoft.com/windows/win32/xinput/xinput-and-directinput
    stringutils::ci_string tmp(m_InterfacePath.c_str(), m_InterfacePath.size());
    if (tmp.find("IG_") == stringutils::ci_string::npos)
        return false;

    // Xbox 360 XUSB Interface
    // {EC87F1E3-C13B-4100-B5F7-8B84D54260CB}
    static constexpr GUID XUSB_INTERFACE_CLASS_GUID = { 0xEC87F1E3, 0xC13B, 0x4100, { 0xB5, 0xF7, 0x8B, 0x84, 0xD5, 0x42, 0x60, 0xCB } };

    m_XInputInterfacePath = SearchParentDeviceInterface(m_DeviceInstanceId, &XUSB_INTERFACE_CLASS_GUID);

    return !m_XInputInterfacePath.empty();
}
```

See
https://github.com/DJm00n/RawInputDemo/blob/master/RawInputLib/CfgMgr32Wrapper.h for a CfgMgr32 wrapper code .